# Django--Form validation (Why can't I manually clean an Integer Form Field)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

This should be pretty straightforward but I'm not figuring it out from the Django documentation.  I have an IntegerField Model Field from which I've created a ModelForm Field.  The field in question contains $ values (price) and it would be preferable from a UX standpoint if the user did not receive a error message ('enter whole number') when they input $10 instead of 10.

I've tried manual form cleaning but it seems that the clean_field method is run after other validation methods.  My reading so far seems to confirm that as well.

```
    def clean_bill(self):
          bill = self.cleaned_data["bill"]
          if '$' in bill:
              bill=bill.replace('$','',1)   
          return bill
```

Is there a way around this while maintaining the IntegerField in the modelform?  Should I just make it a RegexField?

EDIT: I ended up going with a combination of the above and a RegexField.  Still curious if there is another/better way.

```
        bill= forms.RegexField(label=_("Bill"), max_length=10,required=True, regex=r'^\$?[\d]+$',
    error_messages = {'invalid': _("Please enter a whole number.")})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an IntegerField in the model, and a CharField in the form.

You can still use modelform to do this but you'll have to:

1. 'exclude' the model field from the form,
2. write a clean_bill method in the form
3. set the value of the model's field to the parsed integer value

[try this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) and/or [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. According to the [Django docs of form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) it will not even go to your `clean` method and already raise `ValidationError` in the first step (`to_python` method).
There is nothing much you can do on the form level I think. What you could do though is processing the `POST` data in the view before passing it to the form. Some simple example:

```
post_dict = request.POST.copy()   #makes a copy of request.POST so you can modify it
bill = post_dict['bill']
if '$' in bill:
    bill = bill.replace('$','',1)   
post_dict['bill'] = bill
# pass post_dict to your form instead of request.POST
...
```

Comment: Ah, good point about making a copy.  Do you prefer this method of the Regex solution I came up with?

Comment: I think your `RegexField` approach is still the cleaner way to do it. This way is just if you still want to use an `IntegerField`.